# Swift - Saving an Object with Codeable crashes app

Tags: ios, save, swift4, nsuserdefaults, codable

I'm writing an app where I am trying to save an array inside an array via Codable and into `UserDefaults`, but it crashes, with the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Here.UserEntries
>   encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x600000649e70'

Here's how I'm saving it:

```
class UserEntries: NSObject, Codable {
    struct Question : Codable {
        var question: String
        var answer: String

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case question
            case answer
        }

        init(question: String, answer: String) {
            self.question = question
            self.answer = answer
        }
        func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
            var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            try container.encode(question, forKey: .question)
            try container.encode(answer, forKey: .answer)
        }
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            question = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .question)
            answer = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .answer)
        }
    }

    var date: String
    var questions: [Question]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date
        case questions
    }

    init(date: String, questions: [Question]) {
        self.date = date
        self.questions = questions
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(date, forKey: .date)
        try container.encode(questions, forKey: .questions)
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        date = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .date)
        questions = [try container.decode(Question.self, forKey: .questions)]
    }
}
```

where userEntry is:

```
let userEntry = UserEntries(date: String(todayDate), questions: [UserEntries.Question(question: q1Text, answer: q1Answer), UserEntries.Question(question: q2Text, answer: q2Answer)])
```

then

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: userEntry), forKey: "allEntries")
```

What exactly is going wrong? I have a feeling that I can't save an array inside an array, but then how can this be fixed?

Comment: You seem to have confused`NSCoding` and `Codable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
questions = [try container.decode(Question.self, forKey: .questions)]
```

is incorrect. To get array of `Question` you should decode type of array `[Question].self`:

```
questions = try container.decode([Question].self, forKey: .questions)
```

Also, note that `Decodable`/`Encodable` works with `JSONDecoder`/`JSONEncoder`, see [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types). According to this, here is what you need to save (encode to data and then save):

```
let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
if let value = try? jsonEncoder.encode(userEntry) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: "allEntries")
}
```

And the opposite - get data and if it is, try to decode the object:

```
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "allEntries"),
   let userEntry = try? jsonDecoder.decode(UserEntries.self, from: data) {

   // here you get userEntry
}
```

---

Example:

```
let userEntry = UserEntries(date: "1 Sep 18",
    questions: [
        UserEntries.Question(question: "q1Text", answer: "q1Answer"),
        UserEntries.Question(question: "q2Text", answer: "q2Answer")
    ])

let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
if let value = try? jsonEncoder.encode(userEntry) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: "allEntries")
}

let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "allEntries"),
    let userEntry = try? jsonDecoder.decode(UserEntries.self, from: data) {

    print(userEntry.date) // 1 Sep 18
}
```

Comment: @Anthony, what's array of items? It is unclear what you're talking about.

Comment: Hmmm... ok, but when I debug and print the decoded data, it just gives <Here.UserEntries: 0x6000006408d0>, not the array of UserEntries, e.g. [date: "1 Sep 18", Questions(question: "q1", answer: "ans")]

Comment: @Anthony, please, provide full example in your question. I can't really understand what you trying to achieve without full code.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question including what is contained in "UserEntries". Thanks

Comment: @Anthony, ah, it looks like all is fine, isn't it? when you print decoded data - you print the real `UserEntries` object, not a dictionary. for example, try to print `userEntry.date` and will get exactly the same date that you saved before.

Comment: Not quite. When I print that, I just get <Here.UserEntries: 0x604000455870> again...

Comment: Ahhh makes sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To set the model into `UserDefaults` please try this

```
 if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(value) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "allEntries")
 }
```

For decoding:

```
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "allEntries") as? Data {
    if let yourData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(UserEntries.self, from: data) {
        Print(yourData) 
    }
}
```